# How to derive the probability that a first return occurs at the $n$-th step from the transition diagram.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

For a four state $(s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4)$ Markov chain, the transition probability matrix is given by:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
1-a & a & 0 & 0\\
1-b & 0 & b & 0\\
1-c & 0 & 0 & c\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I need to calculate $f_1^{(n)}$, the probability that a first return to state $s_1$ occurs at the $n$-th step.

My thoughts were the following: I calculate $P^n$ and $P^{n-1}$ and then say that the probability that its first return to state $s_1$ occurs at the $n$-th step is $P^n_{s_1, s_1} - P^{n-1}_{s_1, s_1}$?

However, the assignment asks me to calculate the aforementioned probability from the transition diagram. Any ideas on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the chain so that you make the state $s_1$ absorptive. That is, consider the matrix

$$P_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1-b & 0 & b & 0\\
1-c & 0 & 0 & c\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now the probability of the original chain returning to the state $s_1$ for the first time at step $n$ is the same as this new chain being in state $s_1$ at step $n-1$ and not being in it at the step $n-2$, when you give it the initial distribution of what the distribution will be in the original chain after $1$ step, that is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 - a\\
a\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

In other words, you assume one step is already taken in the absorptive chain.